# BigDecimal with RoundingMode.FLOOR is giving unexpected result

Tags: kotlin

I am getting an unexpected result I want to  remove numbers after two number of decimal point

```
BigDecimal(0.55).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.55
BigDecimal(0.56).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.56
BigDecimal(0.57).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.56
BigDecimal(**0.58**).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.57
BigDecimal(**0.59**).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.58
BigDecimal(**0.60**).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.59
BigDecimal(**0.61**).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.60
BigDecimal(**0.62**).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.61
BigDecimal(0.63).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR) //return 0.63
```

Comment: The problem is the `double` value you pass to the `BigDecimal`... Use the constructor that takes a `String` argument, like this: `new BigDecimal("0.62")` and the output of `setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)` will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

You fell victim of double floating point precision. When you write

`0.62`

in reallity it's actually something like

`0.6199999999999626787363666...`.

You should use `BigDecimal` constructor that takes `String` instead of `Double` argument.

Comment: It won`t work in this case.

var a = 0.60 + 0.06
 var b= a.toString()
 BigDecimal(b).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)

Comment: @ShivamPatil You should already perform addition on `BigDecimal`, not on limited precision floating point numbers

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not in the `setScale()` call, but happens before that.  **You're constructing the `BigDecimal` from a `Double` value** — a value which is *close* to 0.58, but isn't exactly.

(`FLoat`s and `Double`s are *binary* floating-point — and almost **no decimal fractions have an exact binary representation**.  In this case, 0.58 is 0.10010100011110101110000101… in binary.  No `Double` can store that exactly; the best if can do is store a value very close to it.)

The `BigDecimal` then does its best to store *that* value as precisely as possible.  You can see this in the REPL:

```
>>> java.math.BigDecimal(0.58)
res1: java.math.BigDecimal = 0.57999999999999996003197111349436454474925994873046875
```

…which makes it obvious why that rounds down to 0.57, not 0.58.

And that holds for all of your problem cases: the nearest `Double` is slightly less than the decimal value you specify, and so rounds down.  (In the others, it's slightly *greater*, so those round as expected.  But the underlying problem is still there.)

The best solution is to avoid floating-point binary numbers entirely, and **use the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor**:

```
>>> java.math.BigDecimal("0.58").setScale(2, java.math.RoundingMode.FLOOR)
res6: java.math.BigDecimal! = 0.58
```

(In this case, of course, there's no longer a need for the `setScale()` call at all, as the value now has a scale of 2 already!  But it does no harm.)